# Find the length of the last word

Tags: python, python-itertools, python-operator

I'm working on the LeetCode [58. Length of Last Word](https://leetcode.com/problems/length-of-last-word/description).

> Given a string s consisting of words and spaces, return the length of the last word in the string.
>
> A word is a maximal substring consisting of non-space characters only.

Example:

> Input: s = "   fly me   to   the moon  "
>
> Output: 4
>
> Explanation: The last word is "moon" with length 4.

This can be trivially solved as follows:

```
return len(s.split()[-1])
```

Assuming the question is asked in an interview, it is customary to impose artificial restrictions, so, let's say that the built-in `split` or `splitlines` can't be used. No problem.

```
from operator import methodcaller, not_
from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile

def lengthOfLastWord(s: str) -> int:
    space = methodcaller("isspace")
    word = takewhile(not_(space), dropwhile(space, s[::-1]))
    return len(list(word))
```

This gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
    return len(list(word))
```

I can, of course, use lambdas instead of `methodcaller`, but knowing that I need to use the same function, `isspace`, the above attempt seems more elegant. In a language like Haskell, I would be able to simply use `isSpace` and `not . isSpace` directly. Python is not Haskell, so, how do I get the same effect?

Please note that there are other ways of solving this question, like using a reverse `for` loop. I'm not looking for other or better options, merely how to make the above code work by negating the callable returned by `methodcaller`.

Comment: What is *not_(space)* ? MRE would be useful https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Codist, `operator.not_`, added the import.

Comment: There is no *_not* operator and even if there was, your code would still induce a NameError exception

Comment: I personally don't find it elegant, but rather unnecessarily overengineered. IMHO

Comment: @Codist It was a typo, the `_` is at the end. The code as shown now _is the MRE_.

Comment: @AlexeyS.Larionov Perhaps, but I'd refer you to this statement in my question "_I'm not looking for other or better options, merely how to make the above code work_"

Comment: @DerSchinken `dropwhile` returns an iterator, so, I don't think it removes all spaces, only the trailing ones. I wondered if there's an elegant way to negate the result of a callable.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Sorry I got a bit confused about how dropwhile worked and yes you are right, and I don't think there is a `methodcaller`-like built-in for negating stuff, you would need to create a function that does that yourself

Answer (score 2):

While your current experiment is just an overcomplication for a simple task, here's a way you can fix the ground of your approach.
Instead of *negating* a whitespace char check, check for *truthiness* of a current stripped char, as the empty string will evaluate to `False`:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def length_last_word(s: str) -> int:
    func = str.strip
    word = takewhile(func, s[::-1].strip())
    return len(list(word))

s = " fly me to the moon "
print(length_last_word(s))  # 4
```

Comment: If we are going to use `strip`, I think there's no need for `func`, since this can be done `word = itertools.takewhile(str.isalnum, itertools.dropwhile(str.isspace, s[::-1]))`. I upvoted you since I didn't realize a function like `isspace` can be used as a reference, since it's invoked on an object instance using a `.`.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, `str.isalnum` will not cover the words like `cross-site`. So it'll fail on `s = " fly me to the know-how "`

Answer (score 1):

What you need in place of `not_` is a function that takes a callable and returns a wrapper function that would call the callable and return its returning value not'd.

Since there is no such high-order function built-in to the Python standard library, you would simply have to write one yourself:

```
def complement(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return not func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

so that:

```
def lengthOfLastWord(s: str) -> int:
    space = methodcaller("isspace")
    word = takewhile(complement(space), dropwhile(space, s[::-1]))
    return len(list(word))

print(lengthOfLastWord(" fly me to the moon "))
```

outputs: `4`

Demo: https://ideone.com/taGtmS

Comment: "_there is no such high-order function built-in_" is what I was after. Upvoted.

Comment: funcy calls it [complement](https://funcy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/funcs.html#complement), might be a better name.

Comment: @KellyBundy Ah awesome package for fans of functional programming there. `complement` is a much more proper name indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired output without losing the structure of your code just by creating a lambda function that negates the result of the isspace method. Here's how you can do it-

```
from operator import methodcaller
from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile

def lengthOfLastWord(s: str) -> int:
    space = methodcaller("isspace")
    not_space = lambda x: not space(x)
    word = takewhile(not_space, dropwhile(space, s[::-1]))
    return len(list(word))

# Example usage:
s = " fly me to the moon "
result = lengthOfLastWord(s)
print(result)  # Output: 4
```

Answer (score -2):

OP here; I settled on the following:

```
def lengthOfLastWord(s: str) -> int:
    word = itertools.takewhile(str.isalnum, itertools.dropwhile(str.isspace, s[::-1]))
    return len(list(word))
```

Comment: `str.isalnum` will not cover the words like `cross-site`.  So it'll fail on `s = " fly me to the know-how "`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest The question states a constraint "s consists of only English letters and spaces ' '.". That's why I linked to the original question.